# Unable to start Mysql Cluster in Windows

Tags: mysql, database, cluster-computing

We have installed MySQL Cluster 5.6.38 on Windows Server 2008 R2 with zip archived packages and using manual configuration for 2 x node. When we try to start the Cluster part, all the nodes (2 management node, 2 data nodes) starts correctly except mysqld node and I got below error.

[All nodes are up and running but mysqld node is stuck at processing message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e83uC.jpg)

Here is the my.cnf

```
[mysql_cluster]
ndbconnectstring=192.168.1.103

[mysqld]
ndb-nodeid=51
ndbcluster
datadir=C:\mysql\cluster\data
basedir=C:\mysql\cluster
ndbconnectstring=192.168.1.103:1186
port=3306

Default-storage-engine=ndbcluster
```

Already gone through the following ref but it did not resolved the issue
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134216/problem-in-starting-mysql-cluster

Comment: So, you post a database administration problem including a link to the site for database administrators on a site for programmers?